# Can't access KVM Host (network brige)

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, centos7

I have a strange problem since I rebooted my KVM Host running CentOS 7.

I have a network bridge which was going fine, I could access my KVM hosts and guests, but since reboot, I can't access the Host. I can ping it, and access it from VMs, but not from my physical network, which means I can't access it using virt-manager over ssh from my machine. Turning off the firewall doesn't help.

Here are some of my configuration :

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcg-enp2s0:

```
HWADDR="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
TYPE="ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
NAME="enp2s0"
ONBOOT="yes"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
BRIDGE="br0"
```

/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcg-br0:

```
DEVICE="br0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
NM_CONTROLLED="no"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="bridge"
IPADDR=192.168.4.10
STP=on
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DELAY="0"
```

/etc/sysconfig/network :

```
GATEWAY=192.168.4.1
GATEWAYDEV="br0"
```

brctl show :

```
br0     8000.90e6ba2e63fd   yes     enp2s0
                                    vnet0
                                    vnet1
virbr0  8000.000000000000   yes
```

ifconfig :

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.4.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.4.255
    inet6 fe80::92e6:baff:fe2e:63fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 90:e6:ba:2e:63:fd  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 508  bytes 97333 (95.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 519  bytes 38241 (37.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::92e6:baff:fe2e:63fd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 90:e6:ba:2e:63:fd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1165  bytes 476382 (465.2 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1393  bytes 131697 (128.6 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 enp3s5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:26:5a:f0:3c:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Boucle locale)
    RX packets 6  bytes 352 (352.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 6  bytes 352 (352.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
    ether 6a:11:26:70:d7:3b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1  bytes 90 (90.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe4d:946c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:54:00:4d:94:6c  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 58  bytes 7174 (7.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 134  bytes 15618 (15.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 vnet1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe56:7ed4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:54:00:56:7e:d4  txqueuelen 500  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 774  bytes 83968 (82.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 867  bytes 397448 (388.1 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Thanks for your help, I'm really lost here.

Comment: the configuration looks fine, maybe there's an IP conflict on the network or some other related issue

Comment: Omg you are right, there was a problem with this adress I changed it and now everything is fine. Can't understand why though, this address is not assigned to anything, maybe it's a router related issue, this adress is supposed to be the one to use as a client to manage the netgear router.
Anyway, I feel really stupid now, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dyasny suggested, it was an IP conflict, so problem solved !